# How to extract data point for a xy coordiante from raster without projected lat lopn coordinates

Tags: r, raster, netcdf, r-raster

Hi am trying to extract values for `xy` point from a sample raster stack `ras_dt`. The `ras_dt` is [EQUATES data](https://www.epa.gov/cmaq/equates#how_to_download_equates_data) with gridded coordinates within the domain of `-115.00,38.00,-110.05,45.00`. How can I change the projection and the `lat` `lon` coordinates of this raster stack so that I can extract data for point `xy` as in the code below.

```
library(raster)
dturl<- "https://www.dropbox.com/s/ztxqpszjfjhpavz/EQUATES_ACONC_O3_SAM.nc?dl=1"
download.file(dturl, "EQUATES_ACONC_O3_SAM.nc")
ras_dt <- raster::stack("EQUATES_ACONC_O3_SAM.nc",varname = "O3") 
ras_dt

# the data domain is -115.00,38.00,-110.05,45.00
plot(ras_dt)

xy <- data.frame(lon=-113.0,lat=40.0)
coordinates(xy) <-  ~lon + lat
extr_dt <- raster::extract(ras_dt, xy) # how to get O3 values for xy here?
extr_dt
```

The ras_dt is in "lambertConformalProjection" with following info:

```
char LambertConformalProjection;
  :grid_mapping_name = "lambert_conformal_conic";
  :latitude_of_projection_origin = 40.0; // double
  :longitude_of_central_meridian = -97.0; // double
  :standard_parallel = 33.0, 45.0; // double
  :earth_radius = 6370000.0; // double
  :_CoordinateTransformType = "Projection";
  :_CoordinateAxes = "x y";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the extent and the coordinate reference system (CRS). Then transform your lon/lat points to that CRS and use extract. From your edited question we now have the CRS.

You specify the "domain", but you need to coordinates in the actual CRS. I do not know what these are, so I will guestimate it, but it will **not be correct.**

The data

```
library(terra)
dturl<- "https://www.dropbox.com/s/ztxqpszjfjhpavz/EQUATES_ACONC_O3_SAM.nc?dl=1"
download.file(dturl, "EQUATES_ACONC_O3_SAM.nc", mode="wb")
ras_dt <- rast("EQUATES_ACONC_O3_SAM.nc", "O3") 
pcrs <- "+proj=lcc +lon_0=-97 +lat_0=40 +lat_1=33 +lat_2=45 +r =6370000.0"
```

Rough estimate of the extent:

```
v <- vect(rbind(c(-115, 38), c(-115, 45), c(-110.05, 38), c(-110.05, 45)), crs="+proj=longlat")
p <- project(v, pcrs)
e <- crds(p) |> apply(2, range) |> as.vector()
e
#[1] -1562368.5 -1025418.3  -139104.3   693662.9
```

Set the extent and the crs

```
ext(ras_dt) <- e
crs(ras_dt) <- pcrs
```

Transform the points to the crs of the raster

```
xy <- vect(cbind(lon=-113.0,lat=40.0), crs="+proj=longlat")
pxy <- project(xy, pcrs)
```

And extract

```
extract(ras_dt, pxy)
#  ID O3_LAY=1_TSTEP=1 O3_LAY=1_TSTEP=2
#1  1         41.88482         40.99662
```

So our raster now looks like this. The spatial resolution should probably be a round number (12,000?)

```
ras_dt
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 70, 45, 2  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 11932.23, 11896.67  (x, y)
#extent      : -1562369, -1025418, -139104.3, 693662.9  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=lcc +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-97 +lat_1=33 +lat_2=45 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#source      : EQUATES_ACONC_O3_SAM.nc:O3 
#varname     : O3 (O3              ) 
#names       : O3_LAY=1_TSTEP=1, O3_LAY=1_TSTEP=2 
#unit        : ppbV            , ppbV
```

Can you find and provide the correct extent somewhere in the documentation? And perhaps ask the data providers to follow the NetCDF conventions such that all the metadata required to use the data is stored in the files.

Comment: The metadata says the data in "LambertConformalProjection" and provides info that I updated in the question. thank you.